# PDFBox TextToPdf keep font

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am currently converting a text document to pdf and rendering it to the browser and cannot seem to keep the font. The font is courier but gets converted to something else when it is converted to a pdf. Is there a easy way to just make it keep the default font? Or at least be able to set it after converting? here is the code.

```
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, List<Report> reports) throws IOException{
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
    PDDocument documentToPrint = new PDDocument();
    for(Report report : reports){
        PDDocument pdDocument = new TextToPDF().createPDFFromText(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(fileDirectory + File.separator + report.getFileLocation()), "UTF8")
        );
        pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(documentToPrint, pdDocument);
    }
    pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + "download.pdf");
    documentToPrint.save(outputStream);
    documentToPrint.close();
}
```

I have also tried setting it like the following before appending the document.

```
    PDDocumentCatalog documentCatalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDResources pdResources = documentCatalog.getPages().get(i).getResources();
    pdResources.add(PDType1Font.COURIER);
    documentCatalog.getPages().get(i++).setResources(pdResources);
```

But that does not seem to work either

Comment: "The font is courier" - no, you don't set any font. Thus the default (Helvetical) is used. Why did you think that courier is used?

Comment: Because I have a the font in the text document as courier. I assumed it would take that font. Yes I have not set a font in the current code. I will edit something that I have tried that does not work when i try to set it.

Comment: See my answer. Your try is well meant but does nothing. Just having the font in the resources is like having cars in the basement but not using it. The font would also have to be set in the content stream.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Your answer is such a easy answer.... lol thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because I have a the font in the text document as courier.

No you don't, editors usually display it with Courier. So you have to set it because the default is Helvetica.

Change this:

```
PDDocument pdDocument = new TextToPDF().createPDFFromText(new InputStreamReader(....
```

to this:

```
TextToPDF textToPDF = new TextToPDF();
textToPDF.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER);
textToPDF.createPDFFromText(new InputStreamReader(....
```

Comment: Wow..... How did I not see a setFont on the TextToPDF...... That worked perfect. Guess this was a lot easier than I thought....